# Sending SMS using internet

Tags: gratis, android, sms

Is there any **reliable** SMS sending Android application or website which fits the following requirements:

1. free (uses internet)
2. no registration required
3. sends SMS worldwide
4. also it should be able to text non-smartphones

I have tried afreesms but it shows like 34 ads on a single web page and is not reliable.

PS: i don't wish to receive SMS i just want to send SMS and get it received safely

Comment: How about Google voice?

Comment: If you want to be able to receive sms (e.g. replies to the messages you send)you most likely will have to go through an account creation of some sort so they can assign you a phone number

Comment: No direct recommendation – but be welcome to check [this list of SMS apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_shortmessage#group_81). Several of them are using web services. Not sure which require registration, though – sending 2-3 SMS per year on average, I never bothered with them ;)

Comment: Do you wish to receive SMS as well? If so, than registration would be required so that you could be assigned a number. Most sites will require registration anyway to prevent spam and misuse.

Comment: You can send SMSs from your Android anyway. And many telecom providers have bundles with free SMSing. So what would that app have to be able to do **in addition**?

Comment: Way2sms.com lets you send messages for free but it requires registration. They also have an android app.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sun.way2sms.hyd.com&hl=en